# Change switched outlet location

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I recently moved to an apartment with no ceiling lights. All wall switches are wired to a specific outlet in each room. Unfortunately, the switch each one controls is in the worst possible location and I can't do any re-wiring.

Is there ANYTHING like what I'm about to describe?

I would like to plug a device to the outlet controlled by the switch and plug a second device to a better located outlet of my choosing. A lamp will be connected to the second device. When I turn the switch on, the first device will send an "ON" signal to the second device which will in turn power up the lamp hooked to it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Interesting question, but it may be [off-topic](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, as it's a product recommendation request.

Comment: There are various WiFi enabled switched receptacle boxes that may help you, except they are controlled by a smartphone app instead of a switch.

Comment: @DanielGriscom I think it is more a question of *is it possible, and how would I do it* rather than *which should I buy or where*.

Comment: Or just run extension cords along the baseboard, if that's mostly out of sight behind furniture.

Comment: Well, many of the smart devices can ALSO talk to each other via WiFi or data over power, with no phone/tablet involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a wireless switch/outlet combination.

There are three basic approaches:

- switch in electric box (powered by line voltage - requires some wiring)
- switch with battery on mounting bracket or loose on table
- smart phone/tablet controlled outlet (no separate switch)

In each case, there is an outlet module that plugs into a standard, always on outlet of your choice. The module is powered or not, depending on the signal received from the remote switch or smart device.

These are available in a number of configurations from numerous sources and are fairly cheap. Search *wireless switch outlet*. An example of a [battery operated switch](http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Wireless-Remote-Wall-Switch-Light-Control-with-Grounded-Outlet-Receiver-18279-18279/204397451) is illustrated below.
[image: wireless switch]

The latter two choices will not use the existing switch or switched outlet. You could use a restricted cover plate to avoid having people try the unused old switch and mount the new wireless switch nearby.

While there may be a transmitter/receiver pair that both plug into outlets, this seems like an unusual configuration, will be harder to find and will likely cost a good bit more

```
 Images and links are illustrative only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```